# How to include images with html-webpack-plugin + twig-loader?

Tags: templates, webpack, twig, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to include an image in my twig template just like simple  tag, but it doesn't want to include. For build, I use HtmlWebpackPlugin and twig-loader;
But if I do the same with html-loader and html template - it works fine.
How to do it right with twig-loader?

my webpack-config:

```
const path              = require( 'path' );
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );

const PATHS = {
    source: path.join( __dirname, './source' ),
    build:  path.join( __dirname, './build' )
};

module.exports = {
    entry:   `${ PATHS.source }/index.js`,
    output: {
        path:     PATHS.build,
        filename: 'webpack.bundle.js'
    },
    module:  {
        rules: [
            {
                test:   /\.twig/,
                loader: 'twig-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
                use:  [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: `${PATHS.source}/index.twig`,
        } )
    ],
};
```

my twig template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./chuck-norris.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "htmlWebpackPlugin-twigLoader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "evisotskiy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "twig-loader": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

my project's structure:

```
.
├── webpack.config.js
├── package.json
├── source
|   ├──index.twig
|   ├──index.js (empty)
|   ├──chuck-norris.jpg
```

and when I execute npm run build I get dir:

```
├── build
|   ├──index.html
|   ├──webpack.bundle.js
```

without chuck-norris.jpg

And when I use html-loader instead twig-loader and html-template instead twig-template - image builds fine. But for my project, I need to use twig templates.
How to do it right with twig-loader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution. Instead of passing to HtmlWebpackPlugin as template the `.twig`-file directly, I passed as template a `.js`-file, inside of which I included a `.twig` file and image, and passed the image to the twig-template as a variable. Now the project looks like this:

my webpack-config:

```
const path              = require( 'path' );
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );

const PATHS = {
    source: path.join( __dirname, './source' ),
    build:  path.join( __dirname, './build' )
};

module.exports = {
    entry:   `${ PATHS.source }/index.js`,
    output: {
        path:     PATHS.build,
        filename: 'webpack.bundle.js'
    },
    module:  {
        rules: [
            {
                test:   /\.twig$/,
                loader: 'twig-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
                use:  [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: `${PATHS.source}/index.twig.js`,
        } )
    ],
};
```

my twig template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ image.src }}" alt="{{ image.alt }}">
</body>
</html>
```

my index.twig.js:

```
const template = require( './index.twig' );

const image = {
    src: require( './chuck-norris.jpg' ),
    alt: "Chuck Norris"
};

module.exports = template( { image } );
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "htmlWebpackPlugin-twigLoader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "evisotskiy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "twig-loader": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

my project's structure:

```
.
├── webpack.config.js
├── package.json
├── source
|   ├──index.twig
|   ├──index.twig.js
|   ├──index.js (empty)
|   ├──chuck-norris.jpg
```

and when I execute npm run build I get builded project I expected:

```
├── build
|   ├──index.html
|   ├──chuck-norris.jpg
|   ├──webpack.bundle.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem recently. But I could not use a solution with handling URLs as parameters.
I've fixed it with extract-loader and html-loader.
Honestly, I don't know how it works, but it works.

This is a task for gulp.
See rules with `test: /\.(jpeg|png|svg|jpg|gif)$/i,` and `test: /\.twig$/,`

```
//region js
task('app:compile', function(){
    return src(path.js.src)
        .pipe(named())
        .pipe(webpack({
            mode: 'development',
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                        use: {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                        use: [
                            {loader: "style-loader"},
                            {loader: "css-loader"},
                            {loader: "sass-loader"},
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(jpeg|png|svg|jpg|gif)$/i,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'file-loader',
                                options: {
                                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                                    outputPath: '../images',
                                    publicPath: 'images',
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.twig$/,
                        use: [
                            'twig-loader',
                            'extract-loader',
                            {
                                loader:'html-loader',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test:/\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'file-loader',
                                options: {
                                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                                    outputPath: '../fonts',
                                    publicPath: 'fonts',
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            devtool: 'source-map',
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.js.dest));
});
//endregion
```

You can see the full version of gulpfile.js at the link
[landing_scratch gulpfile.js](https://github.com/smamykin/landing_scratch/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

Hope it helps somebody who is googling the same questions.

Comment: In fact the answer helped me to implement the assets images to be properly processed within `twig-loader` with Webpack for an advanced Vue CLI setup. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If it's any help, I fixed this very same problem by simply changing the loader that processes the twig template files and adding "html-loader".

This would be the change:

```
{
    test:   /\.twig$/,
    loader: 'twig-loader'
}
```

to

```
{
    test: /\.twig$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'html-loader',
      'twig-html-loader'
    ]
}
```

Of course, you must install those loaders previously if you didn't do it yet.

```
npm install twig-html-loader html-loader --save-dev
```

Henceforth, the images will be processed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I incorporated Twig templates in my advanced SPA build with Vue CLI. The issue I faced was the same as the topic starter.

My Twig templates were compiled fine. But the images in the templates were not copied to build folder. And the paths in resulting output HTML files were not transformed into their Webpack-built-and-hashed paths.

At the same time the images in `.vue` files were copied and the images paths were updated.

To solve this I applied the core of the solution from @s.smsmsm above to my context. Thanks mate.

Briefly: you have to make Webpack to use 3 loaders to process your Twig templates. These are `twig-loader`, `extract-loader` and `html-loader`.

For this I made the specifig `vue.config.js`.

See it [here](https://gist.github.com/WhereJuly/86472a8a90a993273c1b72339aa882d6) with more explanations. The short version follows.

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    outputDir: '.dist',
    pages: {
        main: {
            entry: 'src/js/main.js',
            template: 'src/views/pages/index.twig',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }
    },

    // Here is where the fix actually is made.
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('twig')
            .test(/\.twig$/)

            .use('twig-loader')
            .loader('twig-loader')
            .end()

            .use('extract-loader')
            .loader('extract-loader')
            .end()
            
            .use('html-loader')
            .loader('html-loader')
            .end();
    }

};
```

The Vue CLI config reference is [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/). Its `chainWebpack` option was used to modify the respective Webpack config part via `vue.config.js`. How to add a new loader doc is [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader).